# Is there a way to transform a JavaScript object into another object with cleaner formatting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, object, data-cleaning

When accessing a public register API, I receive more information than I need, and sometimes the data is returned with minor variations. I would like to delete some unnecessary fields, move nested fields to the top level, and rename them. The goal is to standardise format across several different APIs, and keep the memory requirement to a minimum. Example below:

Raw object:

```
[
  {
    startDate: "2022/08/27",
    expiryDate: "2025/08/27",
    party: {
      type: "Business",
      name: "Irregular Expressions Inc."
    },
    location: {
      type: "Office",
      address: {
        locality: "Boston",
        postcode: "PE21 8QR"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    startDate: "2023/12/22",
    expiryDate: "2024/06/22",
    party: {
      type: "Charity",
      name: "Save the Badgers"
    },
    site: {
      type: "Office",
      address: {
        locality: "Badgerton",
        postcode: "BA6 6ER"
      }
    }
  },
]
```

I want to transform this into a smaller, cleaner array:

```
[
  {
    startDate: "2022/08/27",
    expiryDate: "2025/08/27",
    partyName: "Irregular Expressions Inc.",
    location: "Boston"
  },
  {
    startDate: "2023/12/22",
    expiryDate: "2024/06/22",
    partyName: "Save the Badgers",
    location: "Badgerton"
  },
]
```

I have tried the below, but I'm getting an error.

```
module.exports = {
  testTransform: (inputArray) => {
    const outputArray = []
      
    inputArray.forEach(element => {
      outputArray.push({
        startDate: element.startDate,
        expiryDate: element.expiryDate,
        partyName: element.party.name,
        location: element.location.address.locality
      })
    })

    return JSON.stringify(outputArray, null, '  ')
  }
}
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')
```

Am I going in the right direction, or is there a simpler way of doing this? I've searched for this type of transformation but with no luck - what am I missing?

Comment: Why is it `location` in one object, and `site` in the other object? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: @scott raises a good point in the comments. What other differences in structure between the objects might there be other than `location`/`site`? It seems odd that a public API would provide data where the structure differs like that.

Comment: Take a look at the npm package "object-rewrite". It is built exactly for that use case. I might write an answer here later when I have more time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take either `location` or `site` with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) and later the proerties with [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
const
    data = [{ startDate: "2022/08/27", expiryDate: "2025/08/27", party: { type: "Business", name: "Irregular Expressions Inc." }, location: { type: "Office", address: { locality: "Boston", postcode: "PE21 8QR" } } }, { startDate: "2023/12/22", expiryDate: "2024/06/22", party: { type: "Charity", name: "Save the Badgers" }, site: { type: "Office", address: { locality: "Badgerton", postcode: "BA6 6ER" } } }],
    result = data.map(o => ({
        startDate: o.startDate,
        expiryDate: o.expiryDate,
        partyName: o.party.name,
        location: (o.location || o.site)?.address?.locality
    }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: really nice answer.  Don't think you need the second ternary operator on address

Comment: Thank you, I can see that the error is because of the key name variation. This is a good solution, which can be extended to cover any variation in the API response.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you don't know what the outer key will be for the object with the `address` property, if the object will always have 4 properties, when destructuring, you can use rest syntax to collect the final property into a single object, and then take that object's values to get to the address.

```js
const input=[{startDate:"2022/08/27",expiryDate:"2025/08/27",party:{type:"Business",name:"Irregular Expressions Inc."},location:{type:"Office",address:{locality:"Boston",postcode:"PE21 8QR"}}},{startDate:"2023/12/22",expiryDate:"2024/06/22",party:{type:"Charity",name:"Save the Badgers"},site:{type:"Office",address:{locality:"Badgerton",postcode:"BA6 6ER"}}}];

const output = input.map(({
  startDate,
  expiryDate,
  party,
  ...rest
}) => ({
  startDate,
  expiryDate,
  partyName: party.name,
  location: Object.values(rest)[0].address.locality,
}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: It would very much concern me to assume that this is the only additional property in the data, when the only two samples we have already diverge.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read `locality` property of `undefined`. You could use [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to prevent the exception throwing. So, you need to use somthing like `element?.location?.address?.locality` instead of `element.location.address.locality`.

Comment: What does the '?' do ?

Comment: @nickh3, I edited the answer to explain the trick with `?`.

Answer (score 0):

That would require writing a function that recurcively goes throught the contents of an object an returns a non-nested object. The function below is such a function.

```
const flattenObject = (obj) => {
    let result = {};
    for (const i in obj) {
        if ((typeof obj[i]) === 'object') {
            const temp = flattenObject(obj[i]);
            for (const j in temp) {
                result[j] = temp[j];
            }
        }
        else {
            result[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

The function can then be called on each nested object in the array. The map method of arrays would be do nicely for that step.

```
const result = nested.map(n => flattenObject(n))
```

`console.table(result[0])` would produce the output below
[image]

Comment: The OP asked: "I would like to _delete_ some unnecessary fields, move nested fields to the top level, _and rename_ them". The function solves only the second issue. Moreover, it doesn't consider the case if properties have the same names.